# SparkSQL (Spark 1.3) UDF for operations on Date

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a data frame with two string columns having information about date (i.e. "2014-01-01"). I would like to do operations on such columns like cast to date format, and subtract dates. I tried by defining UDF using what I found over internet, for example the following:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DateType
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat

val d = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-mm-dd'T'kk:mm:ssZ")
val dtFunc: (String => Date) = (arg1: String) => DateTime.parse(arg1, d).toDate
val dtFunc2 = udf(dtFunc)
val x = df.withColumn("dt", dtFunc2(col("dt_string")))
```

But when I use that, I got the following error:

```
scala.MatchError: java.util.Date (of class scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef$$anon$6)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.udf(functions.scala:402)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:34)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:39)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:41)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:43)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:45)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:47)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:49)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:51)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:53)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:55)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:57)
    at <init>(<console>:59)
    at .<init>(<console>:63)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1338)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:856)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:901)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:813)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:656)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:664)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:669)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:996)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:944)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:944)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:944)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1058)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Can you help me with this please? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SparkSQL represents timestamps and dates using `java.sql.Timestamp` and `java.sql.Date` respectively. `java.util.Date` won't work here. You can simply extract milliseconds and pass to `java.sql.Date` constructor.

In practice I would consider using `HiveContext` and Hive UDFs. For example you can use `unix_timestamp` with specified pattern (using [Simple Date Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html)) to convert string to **seconds**

```scala
df.selectExpr("*", 
  """unix_timestamp(dt_string, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'kk:mm:ss")""")timestamp)""")
```

and use standard type casting to get date or timestamp.